# Terraform Azure Virtual Machine Extension

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-machine, windows-server-2016, terraform-provider-azure

I have deployed a Windows VM and extension. 
I want to make changes to the VM resource and apply them. 
However, the virtual machine extension resource executes a second time even though it has already ran.

Any tips on fixing this issue? Maybe something in front of the command to execute?

```
`resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "main" {
  name                 = "${var.vm_name}"
  location           ="${azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location}"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name}"
  virtual_machine_name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.name}"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                 = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version = "2.0"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
  {
    "fileUris" : ["<path to file}"],
    "commandToExecute": "sh <name of file> --ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted\""
  }
  SETTINGS
}`
```

Comment: @braingrunt - What type of VM are you running this on? It looks like you're running a Linux CustomScript, but then you're trying to execute it using PowerShell.

Comment: @KJH sorry that was a typo on my end. It's a centos machine.

Comment: Can we see the output of your `terraform plan` where it's claiming to want to re-apply the extension?